# Is there anyway to make export path work on Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, export

I wrote a shell script called `gola` to install golang, and put it on folder `/usr/local/bin`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
curl -LO https://golang.org/dl/go1.16.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
sudo tar -C /usr/local -zxf go1.16.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
echo -e "Installed" && exit 1
```

I run `sudo gola`, and installed golang successfully, but when I run `go version`, the command `go` can't be found, `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin` doesn't work. I think it might be because the script is running in a subshell and it doesn’t work on its parent. I can add `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin` to bash profile, it will works. Besides, is there any other way if I just want it to take effect by running `sudo gola`?

Comment: `PATH` must be defined inside the process which forks a child process. Hence if you want to run _gola_ by a child process, the obvious way is to pass the variable via the environment. If you don't want to change PATH permanently, you can also join it just for a single invocation: ` PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin sudo gola`.  Another possibility is to use a directory which already **is** in your PATH, and create a symlink, i.e. `ln -s /usr/local/go/bin/gola /usr/local/bin/gola`.

Comment: In the script you posted, I don't see any execution of `gola`, So what's the point into modifying the PATH there? The changes are gone as soon as the script exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this when running the script with `sudo`, because the `sudo` program itself runs as a subprocess of your shell (and the shell running the script runs as a subprocess of `sudo`), and subprocesses cannot affect parent processes' environments. (Note: `export` makes a variable export *down* to subprocesses, not *up* to parent processes.)

But since you're already running the `tar` command itself with `sudo` inside the script, why do you need to run the entire script with `sudo`? If you run it with `source` (or `.` if your shell doesn't support that), it'll run in the current shell, and the change to `PATH` will apply to the current shell.

But even that might not be what you really want, because it'll affect *only* the current shell. Next time you open a new one, you won't be able to use `go` until you change the `PATH` for the new shell instance. If you want future shells to be able to use `go`, you *must* add it to someplace like `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: I see, it seems that I can only append `export` to the bash profile. Thank you so much.

Comment: You can write the `export` statement also in a script, which needs it. Keep in mind that the changes will be seen in all child processes of this script.